# Date format of MongoDB (inserting using Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

*This is a 2 question post:*

When I enter a date for a document into MongoDB through an html form, I'll enter it using this format: `YYYY-MM-DD`

For example: `2014-02-13`

However, in MongoDB, it inputs it in the ISOdate format, and while the YYYY-MM-DD will be correct, for whatever reason it will insert one of 3 different hour time stamps:

`ISODate("2016-02-02T00:00:00.000Z")`

`ISODate("2015-02-16T05:00:00.000Z")`

`ISODate("2016-08-02T04:00:00.000Z")`

I never specify the hour when entering dates, but for whatever reason it will always insert into MongoDB an hour of 0, 4, or 5.

I have no idea why it's doing this.

Alternatively, is there a way to remove the 'time' part of the date, seeing as I don't need it? For 'date' all I need is YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

To return only the date as a date object you can try this:

```
var myDate = new Date("2016-05-18T16:00:00Z");
```